# `save(to:for:completionHandler:)` of `UIDocument` crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uidocument

I get crash on every 32 bit device / simulator running iOS 9 on `save(to:for:completionHandler:)`.

Xcode 8.2. Base SDK is 10.2. Target is 9.0. Standard architectures. Swift 3. For both develop and release builds. [Sample project.](https://github.com/stanislavsmida/crashing-document.git)

Could not find if it's known, neither any related issues. Can you recommend any workaround? Should I require 64 bit architecture?

Comment: Please post relevant code and the error description.

Comment: Run the sample project attached on iPhone 5 running iOS 9.

Comment: Look. It has minimum lines of code. Relevant code is actually in title. It crashes somewhere between the save call and completion call. Error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I don't see any reason for downvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The work around is to return NS object, Apple engineer recommended `NSMutableData` specifically:

```
override func contents(forType typeName: String) throws -> Any {  
    guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else { ... }
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        return data
    } else {
        return NSMutableData(data: data)
    }
}
```